# (The candidate) or (candidates) for this position

Tags: grammar

If I have to write a job advertisement, what should I write?

(1) **The candidate** for this position must possess at least a Bachelor's Degree/ Master's Degree in any field.

(2) **Candidates** for this position must possess at least a Bachelor's Degree/ Master's Degree in any field.

From what I have learned,

I think that I can use (1) because there only 1 candidate suits this position ( 1 position has only 1 employee in charge), so that this candidate is specific, so I use article "the" with the word "candidate".

I also think that I can use (2) because I refer to candidates who will apply for this position, there will be several candidates applying for this position and I refer to them in general, I don't know who they are, so that I remove definite article "the" and use the plural form "candidates".

These 2 thoughts confuse me, so I don't know which one is correct to use.

Comment: "At least a Bachelor's degree" includes Master's degree, so there's no need to mention Masters.

Answer (score 2):

Most commonly you'd write "Candidates", but if there's only one position available, you can also say,

> The **successful candidate** will have at least a Bachelor's Degree.

Comment: If there is only one position available, can I use plural form "candidates" like this " Candidates for this position must possess..."?

Comment: Yes, because there's more than one candidate. There's only one *successful* candidate though.